# Email format validation doesn't work with client_side_validation gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I am using gem client_side_validation to validate multiple email addresses at once on client side. It works OK for all validations except email format. It validates email format properly also(I cant save irregular address to db), but not on client side - page reloads when I try to submit irregular email address. Does anybody know where might be problem? I will upload more files if needed.

This is `config/application.rb` file:

```
...
module EmailValidation
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"
    ...
    ...
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

This is `public/javascripts/rails.validations.customValidators` file:

```
clientSideValidations.validators.local["email_format"] = function(element, options){
    if(!/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i.test(element.val())) {
        return options.message;
    }
}
```

This is `lib/email_format_validator.rb` file:

```
class EmailFormatValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
        value.split(/,\s*/).each do |value|
            unless value =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i
                object.errors.add(attribute, :email_format, options)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And this is `Invitation` model:

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :message, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {minimum: 3}
    validates :email, email_format: true
end
```